# PIC Micro assembler under Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: operating-system, pic, ubuntu-11.04

Is there a reliable assembler for PIC micro-controllers (preferably from C) under Ubuntu? I am very familiar with PICs and getting pretty handy with Linux. I used to use an assembler (HyTech or something like that) on my windows box and download using ICProg. I'm not worried about the downloading part, but I can't seem to find an assembler. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

discovered SDCC, which has a supply of include files for various PIC chips. Seems to work fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted to use SDCC in the past but found it lacking and buggy. Instead I have been using the Windows tools through the Wine emulator in Linux. I can run mplab and its assembler as well as the sourceboost compiler through the emulator. It works well enough and can be used from the command line and Makefiles.